# Guess game in C# and i can't make the number of the user guess to show when the game start

Tags: c#, user-interface, int, label

I am creating a Guess game in C# and i can't make the number of the user guess to show when the game start which is 10, it will show only when the user already try 1 guess and it show 10 which in total the program will give the user 11 guesses, can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuessingGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int _randnum;
    int _userguess;

    void GetRandomNumber()
    {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 101;
        Random randomiser;
        randomiser = new Random();

        _randnum = randomiser.Next(min, max);


    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string guessnum = Convert.ToString(_userguess);
        int guess = 0;


        if (int.TryParse(user, out guess))
        {
            if (_userguess == 0)
            {
                buttonGuess.Enabled = false;
                label3.Text = "Game Over";
            }

            else if (guess == _randnum)
            {
                label3.Text = "Good guess";
                buttonGuess.Enabled = false;

            }
            else if (guess < _randnum)
            {
                label3.Text = "Too low guess";
                _userguess--;

            }
            else if (guess > _randnum)
            {
                label3.Text = "Too High guess";
                _userguess--;
            }
            else if (guess < 0 || guess > 100)
            {
                label3.Text = "Your guess is out of the range";
                _userguess--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "Yous should introduce a number";
            _userguess--;
        }
        label2.Text = guessnum;
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRandomNumber();
        _userguess = 10;
    }

    private void buttonNew_Game_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetRandomNumber();
        buttonGuess.Enabled = true;
        _userguess = 10;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please try to ask more specific questions than "can you help me?" See [Why is 'Can Someone Help Me?' not an "actual" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I think his intent is pretty clear, although it is a bit of a word salad. He explained what he wanted and gave his code, what more do you need?

Comment: Side note, your random number is always going to be the same. You need to move Random randomiser outside of GetRandomNumber()

Comment: please read "How to ask a good question" which will help you next time when you ask for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello to all and many thanks for your help and i am sorry if i ask the question wrong, it is my first time here, really sorry and i will read the how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is have a NewGame function which does the game setup and gets rid of the text in label2, and sets the guess counter to 11.

```
private void NewGame()
{
    GetRandomNumber();
    buttonGuess.Enabled = true;
    label2.Text = string.Empty;
    _userguess = 11;
}
```

Then you can use this in both the Form Load and New Game Button Click functions:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewGame();
}

private void buttonNew_Game_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewGame();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Setting the guessnum string at the wrong point. You want it to show the number after the if statement, so you schould set the variable after the if statement. If you set the String before the if statement it gets the inital value of _userguess, which is 10.

To show 10 in the beginning of the game you have to set the text of label2 also when you start a new game.

If you want to let guessnum put out the correct string every time you call it. You should make it a property or method.

```
private string guessnum{ get{ return _userguess.ToString(); } }
```